# Change border color of selected cell

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

When I select a cell in Excel for Mac 2011 it is shown with a blue border:

[image]

**How can I change the color of this border?**

Answer (score 0):

This option isn't controlled by the application (excel), it appears to be controlled by the OS preferences. It can be altered; from [OSX Lion KB on color scheme](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4234):

> 1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, and then click General.
> 2. Choose colors from the Appearance and Highlight color pop-up menus.

Comment: During my research I learned that highlight colors are determined systemwide. So in fact **the question itself has "nothing to do with Excel"** ;-) There are some hacks, exploiting bugs in versions of Excel, which I don't want to use, because they disable other functionality, or some official VBA code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff820716%28v=office.15%29.aspx), which I don't want to use, because I don't have the time to learn VBA just to change cell borders. If you have an answer that you regard as "having to do with Excel", feel free to post it.

Comment: The OSX is already in Microsoft-Excel-2011, as that is for Mac. I didn't accept the answer, so I don't need to explain why it would be acceptable. I'm still looking for a pure Excel solution.